# How to add user control in xaml using metro app win8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, user-controls

I want to use listview as a control so that i can use it in different pages ,

I have created user control named(MyUserControl1) now the problem how i can add in xaml at any palace.

can you suggest me a best way to do it??

Comment: you can check it in your toolbox or by adding its namespace on your xaml page..i would recommend you first check the basics of usercontrol..it is very easy to do that..

Answer (score 3):

Just include the namespace of the user control on the page where you want it, and then use it.

I don't have a machine right now, it will look something like this:

```
<page>
<page.resources>
<xmlns:localContolrs="using:CustomControls">
</page.resources>
<localControls.MyControl ItemsSource="Model.MyList" />
</page>
```

Here I assume MyControl is a List control.

Answer (score 2):

this may help you

Within Visual Studio you can define UserControls by going to Project --> Add New Item and selecting User Control. After defining it there you can then add a reference to it in the XAML of the page you want to use it in. You do this by adding a something along the lines of the following to the root tag of your page.

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    ...
    xmlns:CustomControlName="using:CustomControlNamespace"
    ...>
```

If you want to do it in the same XAML document, I guess you could define the control in the pages resources

```
<Page.Resources>

    <UserControl x:Name="CustomControl">
       ...
    </UserControl>

</Page.Resources>
```